# Streamlining formatting in large document that has been modified by several versions of Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016

I'm fixing up the formating of a large old Word document that has been modified using several versions of Word.  I've converted it to the newest file format .docx. I'm working on formatting issues, such as making sure indentations match up, bullets aline, and the size and font type are correct (though the document is not supposed to have all the same font size and type, for example headings are larger and have a different font).

Are there any tools that would help with this? For example is there anyway to see if bullets in separate paragraphs line up with each other, in terms of their indent? For example is there a way to have a straight ruler or a grid appear on the screen?

Also is there a way to give an indicator when the font formatting changes, for example highlight the first line that switches from Times New Roman to Arial?

I'm using Word 2016 to do this.

Comment: For those wondering, I found right-clicking and selecting "join to previous list" very useful. I think the first item of the different list has to be selected for the option to be available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there would be a tool for that.

There can be specialized tools developed for well defined uses, but I don't think  even getting one of them would be of use for you. This type of work requires very detailed specification how to work with it and deep knowledge of input documents, which customization probably doesn't worth the time for you.

I'd suggest to use **STYLES**, you can define style for each type of text (normal, heading, bulleted list...) and going through the document just select each paragraph and reapply the style.

Comment: It seems word keeps track of which bullets belong to which groups, which is bad because if at a latter time a new set of bullets were added, it's hard to make sure they're flush with the rest of the document (in terms of the margin).